# Want to setEmptyView() of a ListActivity

Tags: android, layout, view

As the title suggests, I want to set a default view for a list activity. I have tried to do this :

```
TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
emptyView.setText("No lists available");
this.getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

But this did not work.

Comment: can you publish your layout?

Comment: It is just a ListActivity with no xml.

Comment: "but this did not work." meaning....Are you getting any error, `TextView` with no text, nothing. Your `Activity` `extends ListActivity`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `emptyView` is never attached to anything, if you use `addView()`:

```
TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
emptyView.setText("It's empty!");
getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Now you'll see it!

---

I wrote a quick Runnable to alternate between empty / "full"...

```
public class Example extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
        ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
        emptyView.setText("It's empty!");
        getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);

        getListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(getListAdapter() == null)
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Example.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"It", "Has", "Content"}));
                else
                    setListAdapter(null);
                getListView().postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView)` instead of just `addView(emptyView)`?  Isn't the `ListView`'s parent just the `ListActivity` that contains this code?

Comment: "Isn't the `ListView`'s parent just the `ListActivity` that contains this code?" Activities are not Views, ListView's parent object cannot be an Activity. So `addView()` is not a method in ListActivity, it's a compile time error... you might have been able to answer these questions for yourself if you tried your suggestion. ;) Anyway there are numerous ways to attach `emptyView` to the layout. This is just the one that introduces the least new concepts.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question.  I'm still learning Android development.  I did try it and get a compilation error, but I didn't understand why.

Comment: *The problem is that emptyView is never attached to anything, if you use addView():*, Could you please elaborate a little but more the sentence ?