# android set empty list message with no xml list

Tags: android, listview, message

I've already tried all possible .setEmptyView suggestions around, but don't work for me, i think thats due to the fact in my code the listview is created programmatically and not through the xml.

I don't know how to set an empty state message with no listview present inside the xml.
Anyone? thanks!

My code for MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// Declare Variables
public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
private static final String TITLE = "title";
private ListView noteListView;
private CursorAdapter noteAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Locate ListView
    noteListView = getListView();

    // Prepare ListView Item Click Listener
    noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);

    noteListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0b4cb6"));
    //noteListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

    // Map all the titles into the ViewTitleNotes TextView
    String[] from = new String[] { TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ViewTitleNotes };

    // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter
    noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_note, null, from, to);

    // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
    setListAdapter(noteAdapter);

}

// Capture ListView item click
OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {

        // Open ViewNote activity
        Intent viewnote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewNote.class);

        // Pass the ROW_ID to ViewNote activity
        viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
        startActivity(viewnote);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Execute GetNotes Asynctask on return to MainActivity
    new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();

    // Deactivates the Cursor
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.deactivate();

    noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    super.onStop();
}

// Create an Actionbar menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Menu Title
    menu.add("Add item")
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.SaveButtonClickListener)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Capture menu item click
OnMenuItemClickListener SaveButtonClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        // Open AddEditNotes activity
        Intent addnote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditNotes.class);
        startActivity(addnote);

        return false;

    }
};

// GetNotes AsyncTask
private class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // Open the database
        dbConnector.open();

        return dbConnector.ListAllNotes();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        noteAdapter.changeCursor(result);

        // Close Database
        dbConnector.close();
    }
}
```

}

**SOLVED** with the workaround shown in another thread (as "Hi I'm Frogatto" suggests below), under onCreate I wrote:

```
TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
emptyView.setText("It's empty!");
getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

EDIT: Please leave this thread, this is a duplicate in terms of correct answer not of the main issue/question. When I searched for this there was no actual case in which ppl weren't using a list inside the XML, so this has a very different title and poses a clearly different situation by all other threads, so again, only the solution is in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to add empty view to your Activity.

- Preserve using ListActivity and do the workaround suggested in this answer:

  - [Want to setEmptyView() of a ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325953/want-to-setemptyview-of-a-listactivity)
- Not using `ListActivity` and using regular Activities and define your `ListView` and empty view in a XML file.

In my opinion, the latter is better, because using the former approach may lead your app to inconsistency as in newer versions of Android structure of `ListActivity` might change.

Comment: Thanks! solution at the link you provided works (the workaround).